# Dragging in jQuery isn't working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an image I want to change image when it drags but it won't?

I am using this jQuery:

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
    revert: true,
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        $( this )
            .addClass( "choppedonion" )
            .find( "section.onion" )
                .html( "" );
    }
});
```

And then this HTML:

```
<section class="onion" id="draggable"></section>
```

Why isn't it working? The section uses a background image to show.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to `find`. `find()` searches for child nodes. Where as `section.onion` is at the same level

Comment: @karthikr: Or rather, `this` *is* `section.onion`.

Comment: Have you tried it on a <div> instead of <section> ?

Comment: .draggable is only available in [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) I assume you've loaded the library but not tagged your question accordingly?

Comment: whats not working? the class wont change? the html wont change? it wont drag at all? are you dragging a `section.onion` or an element containing a `section.onion`?

Comment: The `drag` event handler is called continually while dragging. I think you want to handle `start` instead (or perhaps pass a `helper` to create a clone that gets dragged).

Comment: FYI the draggable part [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/EY72B/1/) not sure what you're trying to do in the `drag` function but I see no errors. What's not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
    revert: true,
    start: function() {
        $(this).addClass("choppedonion")
    },
    stop: function() {
        $(this).removeClass("choppedonion")
    },
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        //whatever
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bykMt/